# Working with current session in different port of webDriver is possible?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber

I am using remoteDriver in a cucumber java selenium framework. I need to perform a batch run with many test cases. Right now, only the first test case is running and i get the error:

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id`

Every run occurs in different ports.

How can i set the port? I run in chrome browser.
How can i resolve this: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id.`

Comment: NoSuchSessionExpection happens when you try to perform any action after quitting the session. Documentation https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException.html

Comment: Hi @mk_ I am not quitting the browser, but as i am using the remoteDriver, it is launching another browser in a new window with anew port. But the control is still staying in the old window.